# How to inject Spring bean to vertx jersey instance

Tags: java, spring, vert.x

I am trying to use vertx jersey framework along with Spring. I am trying to inject a Spring created bean with the Jersey annotation to be used by the vertx jersey framework, but I am facing a problem with the injection.

Here is my Main code

```
public class Main {

  private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application_context.xml");
    EComAppController eComAppController = (EComAppController) context.getBean("ecomAppController");
    List<Object> instances = new ArrayList<>();
    instances.add(eComAppController);
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.runOnContext(aVoid -> {

      // Set up the jersey configuration
      // The minimum config required is a package to inspect for JAX-RS endpoints
      vertx.getOrCreateContext().config()
          .put("jersey", new JsonObject()
              .put("port", 8080)
              .put("features", new JsonArray()
                  .add("org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.freemarker.FreemarkerMvcFeature"))
              /*.put("packages", new JsonArray() //This is working, but then vertx-jersey framework will initialize new object which I dont want.
                  .add(eComAppController.getClass().getPackage().getName()))*/
              .put("instances", instances)//This approach not working
          );

      // Use a service locator (HK2 or Guice are supported by default) to create the jersey server
      ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorUtilities
          .bind(new HK2JerseyBinder(), new HK2VertxBinder(vertx));
      JerseyServer server = locator.getService(JerseyServer.class);
      JerseyOptions options = server.getHandler().getContainer().getOptions();
      //options.getInstances().add(eComAppController);
      // Start the server which simply returns "Hello World!" to each GET request.
      server.start();
      //Getting exception on above line
      LOGGER.info("Server started successfully");
    });

  }
}
```

I am getting the following exception using the above code

```
SEVERE: Failed to start the jersey container
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rt.controller.EComAppController cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow "Tell Don't Ask" principle.
Instead of passing `EComAppController` (which Vert.x tries to serialize), consider wrapping this bean in a verticle, and communicate with it using EventBus:

```
class EcomVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    EComAppController eComAppController;
    @Override
    public void start() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application_context.xml");
        this.eComAppController = (EComAppController) context.getBean("ecomAppController");

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("ecom-question", (message) -> {
            // eComAppController does something with the message
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. But I am not creating verticle. I am using Vertx Jersey framework.

Comment: Yes using above